# Cannot find the startup.sh and shutdown.sh on centos with tomcat8 installed on it

Tags: linux, tomcat, centos, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using elastic beanstalk and in preconfiguration, I choose Tomcat and then beanstalk install the tomcat 8 automatically on centos. So far so good since I do not need to install Java SDK and Tomcat on my own. The problem is I cannot find the .sh files such as startup.sh and etc. For instance, my tomcat folder is in:

```
/usr/share/tomcat8/
```

and there is a webapps folder inside it. Also in the above path, there is a bin folder which is empty. Also when I try the following:`ps -ef | grep java| grep -v grep | wc -l`

I get 1 which means that Tomcat is running. Also, I can see a sample webapp when I use the IP address in the address bar so this means that the tomcat is running properly.
When I search for the file like startup.sh like the following:

```
find -name 'startup.sh'
```

I get nothing. How is it possible that tomcat is installed but there is no startup.sh and shutdown.sh. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using **CentOS 7**, it might be `systemctl start tomcat` or `systemctl start tomcat8` - you get a list of possibly installed unit files by `systemctl list-unit-files | grep tomcat`.

Comment: Thanx when I use the command it says :  -bash: systemctl: command not found

Comment: What you mentioned did not work however it made me think deeper and after investigation I noticed that as soon as I put the files in webapps in the share folder of tomcat then it automatically publish the stuff on the tomcat so no need to restart the tomcat at all. So I will accept your answer + the my explanation for future people who view this post

Answer (score 1):

I met the same issue when I use `yum install tomcat` in a docker, which is using centOS7,

cannot find `startup.sh` and `shutdown.sh` , neither `systemctl` and `service` command

implementing a temporary solution: run docker with command
`/user/sbin/init`

it make systemctl command available in docker, 
hope a nicer way:)

Answer (score 1):

```
# systemctl cat tomcat

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/tomcat/server start
```

When using systemd then there is no startup.sh/shutdown.sh script needed anymore to run it as system service. That's pre-systemd style as on CentOS6. I have run the shown command in a docker container however I had build it using the [docker-systemctl-replacement](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-replacement). If you do not want to run it as a system service then you can just spin up a tomcat instance like shown above, and stop with control-C as usual.

[centos-tomcat.dockerfile](https://github.com/gdraheim/docker-systemctl-images/blob/master/centos-tomcat.dockerfile)

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. but after this, I came into a new problem, that my tomcat stops randomly at any point of time without any error logs. I do have multiple services in server.xml and all the services are running in different ports. I do not find any problem in my server.xml